# appending a plus sign (+) to emails does not work

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I am sending triggered e-mails using salesforce marketing cloud.

when I send an e-mail to `user+new@test.com` the expected behaviour (see link below) is to receive it on `user@test.com`.

This does not seem to work. Can someone confirm that? Any way I could replace it?

https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~watrous/plus-signs-in-email-addresses.html

Comment: As your link says this is dependent on the mail server system. 
This definitely works with addresses based on the gmail framework. 
Try it with a gmail account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a valid assumption to make, unless the email provider supports that syntax. For example, Gmail allows plus in this manner to allow users to determine a folder to save incoming emails to based on the part after the plus sign. Other service providers allow it as a literal character in a username, and some refuse to allow the plus sign at all. Make sure that the email address that you're testing with supports this behavior.